# Sammy routes based on select element and knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, sammy.js

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="enable: addressBookEntries(), options : addressBookEntries,
               optionsText: 'address',
               value: selectedAddressBook,
               optionsCaption: 'Select address'"></select>
```

and a Sammy route like :

```
Sammy(function () {
    this.get('#addressBook/:id', function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

Is there any way to make that when users changes option on the dropdown it updates the browser location and execute the sammy route ?

I know I can make a computed that do this but I was looking for some way to actually populate the id from an observable. Is it clear?

Comment: I have never tried this, but having looked at parts of Sammy before, I do not believe there is any way to do what you want. Sammy is based off of JQuery, which has no concept of observables, and so, without a computed, you cannot change the address of the URL.

Comment: Offcourse its possible, but its not built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you would need to update the hash route when the observable changes and have Sammy respond to the route.

Add something like this to your viewmodel:

```
selectedAddressBook.subscribe(function(newValue){
   // validate newValue
   // update the hash with the newValue
   window.location.hash = "#addressBook/" + newValue;
});
```

Comment: can you provide an example to change hash?